# Magento 2 - List child SKUs of category on category page

Tags: magento2, category, category-products

I hope someone can help - editing the `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` most likely buy inserting a new phtml file, how can I list all of the child SKU's of the parent category on the category page?

Example...
Parent category - Electrical
8 child categories, 1 of which being Batteries
Batteries has 2 products assigned, SKU 1234 and 2345

What I would like, on the Electrical category page, the two SKU's (1234, 2345) listed on the Batteries category card

A visual example... http://i.ibb.co/VM1D222/Example2.jpg

Comment: Please clear your exact requirement. What I understand is you want to products of parent categories on current category. Right ? OR you want to show product of child categories on current category page ??

Comment: Ok, So I have a category called Electrical, which has 8 sub categories, one of those sub categories is called Batteries which has 2 products assigned.
On the Electrical category page, under the Batteries card, I would like the child SKUs listed. Like this https://i.ibb.co/VM1D222/Example2.jpg

Comment: Okay now which products do you want to be shown on Electricals (0 as it dont have any products) and on Batteries page (you want to show products associated with Batteries category). Right ? Means do you want to show products of current category

Comment: in question you mentioned "how can I list all of the child SKU's of the parent category on the category page"

Comment: Please see my example visual example https://i.ibb.co/VM1D222/Example2.jpg

Comment: Had anyone had any more thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
 <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $current_category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
  $parent_category = $current_category->getParentCategory();
  $cat_id = $current_category->getId();   
  $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');         
  $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($cat_id);         
  $categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {

        echo $product->getSku() . ' - ' . $product->getName() . '<br />';
    }
```

Comment: That is close, the problem I have now is, I have a category called Electrical, which has no products, under that category I have a category called Batteries which has a product assigned, but every category under Electrical is showing the child SKU, here is a an example... https://i.ibb.co/7nSTgKw/example.jpg

Comment: what is the relation in Electrical and Batteries

Comment: Electrical is the parent category of Batteries category

Comment: Basically what I am trying to achieve is this... https://www.soakandsleep.com/furniture/all - in the source under the TrustPilot widget there is all the SKU's listed (<div class="trustpilot-widget" data-locale="en-US" data-template-id="54d39695764ea907c0f34825" data-businessunit-id="52fe0d35000064000578390b" data-style-height="33px" data-style-width="100%" data-sku="Clerkenwell_furniture_collection_Grouped,FB2-CL,FB3-CL,FB4-CL,FST-CL,FCH-CL,FCHMCL,LWC2FG,bamboo_and_canvas_storage")

Comment: One parent can have N no of children categories you want all child products ??

Comment: Would it just be the level above then? So not Electrical, just Batteries?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$current_category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
$parentId = $current_category->getParentCategory()->getId();

$cat_id = $current_category->getId();   
$childCats = $current_category->getChildrenCategories();

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($parentId);         
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

// echo $parentId;

// echo 'count -- '.$category->getProductCount();
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {

    echo $product->getSku() . ' - ' . $product->getName() . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: This will show all products of all subcategories of current category, let me know if it works for you. Just one suggestion do not use OM directly

Comment: This again has listed all the SKUs that are under the Batteries category under all the Batteries sibling categories, e.g. https://i.ibb.co/vCNCY3y/Screenshot-2019-03-27-at-12-43-01.png

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: Now no SKU's are showing?

Comment: Any ideas?? Thank you for your help so far.